# Why can't the compiler deduce template argument for this simple function?

Tags: c++, templates

This is a very simple template issue (simple for C++ gurus I think), involving making generic math functions.  I have a simple Epsilon function, like this:

```
template<class T>
static T Epsilon()
{
    return std::numeric_limits<T>::Min();
}
```

and I want to assign it to some variable, like this:

```
float epsilon = Math::Epsilon();
```

, alas, I get a compilation error:

> error C2783: 'T Math::Epsilon(void)' : could not deduce template
>   argument for 'T'

I can assign it like this, without error:

```
float epsilon = Math::Epsilon<float>();
```

I thought the template engine would be able to see that my T is "float", but apparently it cannot.  What have I failed to understand here?

Comment: `template argument deduction` needs argument :)

Comment: There is already a [epsilon defined in numeric limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon).

Comment: This wasn't that specifically.  I just used it as an example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that C++ does not feature a full Hindley-Milner deduction algorithm. Instead, it deduces the template arguments *from the function arguments*.

Your function has no argument, hence no template parameter can be deduced.

Answer (score 4):

Template argument deduction only works on function arguments, not on the return type. This is similar in that you cannot overload functions on their return type (for the simple reason that you are allowed not to use the returned value, and the compiler couldn't deduce the appropriate function in that case).

Answer (score 4):

In general, function template parameters are only deduced based
on the types in the arguments.  No arguments, no deduction.  To
work around this, you need to get the compiler to deduce
a conversion.  Something like this, for example:

```
struct Epsilon
{
    template <typename T>
    operator T() const
    {
        return std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
    }
};
```

In this case, the call to `Epsilon` in fact creates an object,
which is implicitly convertible to the target type; the
deduction will take place when the compiler looks for the
conversion, not when it tries to call the "function".

Comment: That's interesting.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I do not suggest you to do that, but in the case you really need to deduce the type from the returned value epsilon, you can do something like:

```
float epsilon{};
epsilon = Math::Epsilon<decltype(epsilon)>();
```

The returned value type can be deduced. If you want avoid redundancy and use a single `float`, you can also do:

```
auto e = Epsilon<float>();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a fundamental problem with your approach.

The return value is not part of the function signature. That means there can only be one function with that return value.

To understand, try to compile

```
float epsilon = Math::Epsilon<float>();
int epsilon = Math::Epsilon<int>();
```

It will not work, because the functions would have the same signature.

Take a look at `std::numeric_limits` in C++11 to make a working template. The template argument can not be deduced though, because it first has to be evaluated and then can be assigned.

Comment: I tried and the code compiles and works just fine on C++11 (even without scoping).